# Centralized update for third party apps

Tags: macos, software, upgrade, 3rd-party

I kind of hate it when applications, which I start, at first search for updates. It's not the updates. Well I fire up an app because I want / need to use it (now). I liked the centralized, system wide update which Linux offered. And `SoftwareUpdate` just checks Apples software.

*Is there a way to centralize the updates of the third party applications?*

So far I know about `Macports` and `Fink` which update quiet like Linux, but I also use e. g. iTerm, Transmission etc. which would still be left out.

I also heard little about [Appcasting](http://connectedflow.com/appcasting/), which uses RSS to announce updates, and which is used by some apps I use, but I don't know any URLs.

Comment: are there any better apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [AppFresh](http://metaquark.de/blog/appfresh/). It's nearly perfect. A lot of apps are recognized, even new ones and widgets and prefpanes too.

It's backed up by [iusethis](http://osx.iusethis.com/) to check for update, but can also check for Apple or Microsoft Office updates.

Comment: For me, AppFesh is just crashed randomly... so I choose MacUpdate one.

Comment: @nanda, weird, I can't even remember the last time AppFresh crashed on me.

Answer (score 2):

MacUpdate and Versiontracker both offer custom apps that do specifically this. However, after a free period, they're paid for I believe. MacUpdate app is my preferred of the two, available [here](http://www.macupdate.com/desktop/).

Answer (score 1):

[Bodega](http://appbodega.com/) acts like the app sore in iTunes, but it's for desktop apps. It includes a version checker/updater in the "Applications" section.